# Does using IDs in the URL make Google view the URLs as duplicate?

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, rel-canonical

In my site, I use query string for navigate between products.

Example:

- `/ProductView.aspx?ProductID=1`
- `/ProductView.aspx?ProductID=2`
- `/ProductView.aspx?ProductID=3`

Am I faced with link duplicates from an SEO perspective when I do this? To solve this problem, should I use the `<link rel=”canonical” href=”www.test.com/ProductView.aspx” />` tag?

Comment: I have edited this question to make it acceptable to this site.  You can post again to ask your other questions. You were still asking two very different questions at once.  For this site, you need to pick one question make the title match.   You can ask your other questions using the "Ask Question" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google recognizes your URLs with parameters and as different because the id is different. I suppose that the product pages have not the same content; therefore, there is no duplicate content between your URLs; thus, you don't need to use the `rel="canonical"` tags between pages.